# Emit information from a library without run-time cost if none is wanted

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

I am author of a library with a number of optimization algorithms, in which I already invested quite a bit of profiling/tuning. I am currently writing front-end programs for this library.

At the moment, the library routines themselves are pretty much black boxes. Consider a method along the lines of `bool fit(vector_t const& data, double targetError)`. They work and do what I want them to do, but for the frontends, a bit of runtime information would be nice. For example, it would be nice if information like "current error" or "number of iterations left" *could* be displayed. I do not want a simple `if (verbose) cerr << "Info\n";` pattern, since the library should be equally usable in a GUI environment.

I deliberately write *could*, because I want to keep the impact of this information emission as low as possible. How can I define and implement an interface, that

- Emits an object with run-time information whenever an observer is registered
- has minimal run-time costs *with regards to the algorithm* if an information object is emitted, and
- has close to no run-time costs if no observer is registered?

Basically, the run-time costs of this optional introspection should be as low as possible, and close to zero if no introspection is wanted. How can this be achieved? Do libraries exist for this? (I guess the answer is yes, and probably hidden in the Boost project, but without known what to look for…)

Comment: Have you *tried* using a simple `if` check? Have you profiled or otherwise measured it? The impact should be very little if the condition is false.

Comment: I see that I formulated the question in a way that made it easy to misunderstand; sorry for that. The `if (verbose)` part is not the problem, even if I employ an observer pattern (`if (hasObservers())`), because it can still be reduced to a integer comparison. I worry about the actual emission of information if this check resolves to `true`: How can I emit an information object, e.g. a simple `struct` with data fields, without impairing the execution of the actual algorithm?

Comment: You could allow the user to pass the callback that will be called by your functions as needed (as, for example, clCreateContext does in OpenCL API). If user passes no callback, the if is likely to be ignored. If he does pass it, well, it is up to user to deal with information as he pleases (fast - just break out, panic, store to some tmp variable etc; or slow - log to file, to stdout etc).

Comment: The problem here is not really sending the information to the observer, that will be quick enough. The problem as I see it is that unless it's done asynchronously then the observer itself could impact the runtime performance in ways that you can not predict. For example, if the observer decides to send the data to a tape-drive and not return control to your algorithm before the tape-write is finished, then it will impact your "performance" is a very big way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move all costs to compile time!

The easiest approach is:

```
template<bool logging>
bool fit(vector_t const& data, double targetError)
{
    // ... computations ...
    if (logging) {
        std::cout << "This is log entry\n";
    }
    // ... computations ...
}
```

Usage:

```
fit<true>(data, epsilon); // Will print logs.
fit<false>(data, epsilon); // Will not print logs with zero overhead.
```

Nowadays almost any compiler will optimize all such checks out while compiling.

A more flexible approach is to pass a logger as a template parameter:

```
class ConsoleLogger
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    static void log(Args... args) {
        // Print args using compile-time recursion.
        // Anyway, this prototype is only an example.
        // Your may define any logging interface you wish.
    }
};

class FileLogger
{
    // Some implementation of log() ...
};

class RemoteCloudLogger
{
    // Some implementation of log() ...
};

class NullLogger
{
    template<typename... Args>
    static void log(Args... args) {
        // Intentionally left blank. Any calls will be optimized out.
    }
};

template<typename Logger>
bool fit(vector_t const& data, double targetError)
{
    // ... computations ...
    Logger::log("Current error: ", currentError);
    Logger::log("Iterations passed: ", i);
    // ... computations ...
}
```

Usage:

```
fit<ConsoleLogger>(data, epsilon); // Will log to console.
fit<RemoteCloudLogger>(data, epsilon); // Will log to a file on remote cloud server.
fit<NullLogger>(data, epsilon); // Any calls to Logger::log will be optimized out, yielding zero overhead.
```

Obviously, you can write a logger class which will collect all logged information to a structure with introspection data.

For example, you might define `fit`'s interface as follows:

```
template<typename Logger>
bool fit(vector_t const& data, double targetError, IntrospectionData& data)
{...}
```

and define only two logging classes: `IntrospectionDataLogger` and `NullLogger`, whose `log` methods accept a reference to `IntrospectionData` structure. And again, the last class contains empty methods that will be thrown away by your compiler.

Comment: Great, exactly the flexibility I need!

Comment: I used the same `template <bool>` trick for a function with time measurement vs. without (to feed statistics if required).

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate the struct on the stack and pass a reference to the observer. The observer can then do whatever is necessary with the struct, e.g. copy it, print it, display it in a GUI etc. Alternatively, if you want to track only one or two properties you might want to just pass them as separate arguments.

```
class Observer
{
...
public:
     virtual void observe(MyInfoStruct *info) = 0;
}

...
if(hasObservers()) // ideally inline
{
    MyInfoStruct info = {currentError, bla, bla};
    for(observer : observers)
    {
        observer->observe(&info);
    }
}
```

That way there should be no overhead when there are no observers except for the `if` statement. The overhead for emitting the information should be dominated by the virtual calls to the observers.

Further optimizations:
You may want to outline the presumably cold observer iteration code into a separate function to improve code locality for the hot path.

If there are any frequent virtual calls in your code anyway, consider adding an "Observed" version of the interface and try to perform the observation work there, and completely omit it from the original version. If the observed version can easily be injected once upon placement of the observer, you may be able to omit checking for observers redundantly. If you just want to track arguments to a function this is easy, by making the "Observed" version just forward to the original, however if you want to track information while an algorith is running this may not be practical.

Depending on what you want to track, it may be possible to write this as a template:

```
struct NoObserverDispatch {
     bool hasObservers() {return false;}
     void observe(MyInfoStruct *) {}
};

struct GenericObserverDispatch {
     bool hasObservers() {return !observers.isEmpty();}
     void observe(MyInfoStruct *) { for (obs : observers) obs->observe(info); }
     private:
     vector<unique_ptr<Observer> > observers;
};

template<typename ObserverDispatch>
class Fitter
{
     ObserverDispatch obs;
     virtual bool fit(vector_t const& data, double targetError)
     {
         ...
         if(obs.hasObservers()) { // will be optimized away unless needed
             MyInfoStruct info = {currentError, bla, bla};
             obs.observe(&info);
         }
     }
};
```

Obviously this assumes that you can replace the `Fitter` whenever an observer is placed. Another option would be to let the user pick the template instantiation, but that may be less clean and has the drawback that you will have to ship the code.